# Javascript: document.createElement('html') - document is not defined

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a .js file and want to use DOM in there. If I try the following code;

```
var element = document.createElement('html'); // line 13
element.innerHTML = myString; // html String
```

I´ll get the Exception

```
ReferenceError: "document" is not defined.
(<Unknown source>#13) in <Unknown source> at line number 13
```

what is missing?

EDIT:
there is no file loading. I only get the html-String from java and want to work with it in a javascript file, to give some values back to java later

EDIT:
-> Title could be: **How can I get a DOM-Element from a Html-String in Javascript**

Comment: Did you wait on a window ready event or just start this code as soon as the js file is loaded? If you don't know what i mean, post the entire function and how you call this function.

Comment: there is no file loading. I only get the html-String from java and want to work with it in a javascript file, to give some values back to java later

Comment: Javascript should always be used in a browser context, so how does your html/jsp/asp... page link to this js? If it isn't in browser context, document actions will never work.

Comment: Well, that is important data for your question. Can you provide it in the core of the question.

Comment: so you run this code in javascript engine of java?

Comment: @namlik No it should not. Why? Javascript is used a lot server side with node now for example.

Comment: While it might be used alot with nodejs, you cannot call document actions in it. As the document property is exclusive to browsers.

Comment: With this I agree.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude No. https://nodejs.org

Comment: no in a javascript engine

Comment: And how is supposed to manage a document without a document?

Comment: So, how can I get a DOM-Element from a Html-String in Javascript :/

Comment: Well, you can't. Take a look at [this](http://www.richardrodger.com/2013/09/27/how-to-make-simple-node-js-modules-work-in-the-browser/#.VynkfISLTcs) to learn how to connect nodejs with the browser. But without a browser you cannot create DOM elements in javascript.

Comment: @suggi87 how do you execute this code?java js engine? and there is java library like `jsoup` to parse html

Comment: @FastSnail I run it with a ScriptEngineManager, with the ScriptEngine "JavaScript" does that help?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like document is undefined because there is no document. The JS isn't imbedded in a webpage, so there is no document.

Comment: Is it possible to create the document from the html-String?

Comment: @suggi87 I don't think so, the only way to get a document is to embed the script in a page. Keep in mind that I am only somewhat experienced in the more complicated stuff.